# Why iOS does not allow downloading PDF/doc/ ... files?

Tags: ios

why iOS does not allow to download PDF into some 'Downloads' folder (like images can save into Photo Library and available through out the iPhone). For now, we can open document in iBooks and store there. Is there any security risk for saving file into some shared folder ?

Answer (score 6):

The lack of a file system in iOS isn't due to any sort of security risk or technical concern. Rather, it is a design decision that was made by Apple.

Apple decided that instead of dumping all data into a central file system accessible by the user, each type of content should be managed by the app that uses that content. So, music files are managed by the music app, email data is managed by the mail app, and photos are managed by the photos app.

This design decision carries over to documents (PDFs, Word docs, etc.) as well. Document files can only be opened by the apps that use those files. So, PDFs can be opened in iBooks, but they can also be opened in other apps that support those formats (such as GoodReader and Dropbox, among others).

Steve Jobs explained this type of OS design in a 2005 interview (excerpted [here](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/06/steve-jobs-on-the-file-system/)). While the interview comes two years before iOS was introduced, it has clearly informed the design of iOS.